# Phonegap: What does device.name return?

Tags: android, cordova

I know it returns the device name, and that's its often a combination of the code name and the phone name.

But what I need is a more exact list (for android phones). Does such a list exist?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: device.name returns the name of the device's model or product. This value is set by the device manufacturer and may be different across versions of the same product.

Comment: Yep. It would have been really nice with a list of these (eg the most common ones).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is still interesting to you but Google has a list as CSV and PDF up [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en-GB). Of course this list only covers Android devices.